# Using Bot commands with client events - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord Python Bot that uses client events, such as `on_member_join`, and commands (`@bot.command()`). The `on_member_join` event is not working with `@bot.event`, but `on_ready` works just fine.
The code is as it follows:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    public = 'welcome, {0.mention}:'.format(member)
    await member.guild.system_channel.send(public)


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong :sunglasses:')



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I'd appreciate if someone helps me with this.

Comment: Have you defined intents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see youre trying to do a welcome message. You can do ctx.send instead of member.send you just gotta pass in ctx.

This is my welcome message:

```
#Welcome DM
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(f'Hey {member.mention}, thanks for joining {member.guild.name}!')
```